# Azure Storage accounts container public access level has dissabled

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-blob-storage

I have an Azure account with pay as you go subscription. I created Storage account as discribe in following link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-customize-ui

But I can not change the Public access level of the container. It always has disabled as attached images.

[image]

[image]

Can anyone help me to enable this. I spent lot of time on reading docs. But can not find any.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to set **`AllowBlobPublicAccess`** to true on your storage accounts. You can do this in the Portal under Configuration for the storage account by setting "Blob public access" to Enabled.

Comment: I am not sure if you are facing this situation https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/6521

Comment: In configuration menu, I enabled Blob public access property.